# Taylor spectrum of commuting operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, exterior-algebra

**Taylor spectrum of commuting operators**

Fom the following [paper](http://operator.pmf.ni.ac.rs/www/pmf/publikacije/faac/2017/FAAC-9-2/faac-9-2-4.pdf) (M. Ch—o, H. Motoyoshi, B. Na¡cevska Nastovska: On the joint spectra of commuting tuples of operators and a conjugation) we have

[image]

> Let  $A= \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $I= \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. The Harte spectrum of $(I,A)$ is equal to
>   $$\sigma_H(I,A)=\{(1,1);(1,-1)\}.$$
>   I want to calculate the taylor spectrum of $(I,A)$ denoted $\sigma_T(I,A)$

According to the following paper of Taylor:
J. L. Taylor, A joint spectrum for several commuting operators, J. Functional Anal. 6(1970), 172-191.

we have

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what text is the first picture from?

Comment: @M.G. Please see my editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Taylor spectrum happens to be the same $\sigma_T(I,A) = \{(1,1), (1,-1)\}$. Let $R_X(\lambda) = (X-\lambda)^{-1}$ be the resolvent of $X$. You have the identities
\begin{gather*}
  \begin{bmatrix} I-\lambda & A-\mu \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} R_I(\lambda) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = I, \\
  \begin{bmatrix} R_I(\lambda) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} I-\lambda & A-\mu \end{bmatrix}
  + \begin{bmatrix} -(A-\mu) \\ I-\lambda \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & R_I(\lambda) \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix} , \\
  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & R_I(\lambda) \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} -(A-\mu) \\ I-\lambda \end{bmatrix} = I ,
\end{gather*}
whenever the resolvent $R_I(\lambda)$ exists. These identities (in homological algebra, they are known as a *contracting homotopy* for this complex) imply that, whenever $\lambda$ is not in the spectrum of $I$ (namely, when $R_I(\lambda)$ exists), Taylor's Koszul complex is exact and hence the corresponding value of $(\lambda,\mu)$ does not belong to $\sigma_T(I,A)$. You can write similar formulas, but using $R_A(\mu)$ instead. Hence, you have reduced the calculation to $\sigma_T(I,A) \subseteq \{ (1,\mathbb{C}) \} \cap \{ (\mathbb{C},1), (\mathbb{C},-1) \} = \{ (1,1), (1,-1) \}$. Now it's just a matter of checking that for these values of $(\lambda,\mu)$ the Koszul complex really does fail to be exact, which is easy to see from the known common eigenvectors of $I$ and $A$.

**High brow explanation:**
A cochain map between two complexes descends to a map in cohomology. For example, the identity cochain map induces the identity map in cohomology. For any complex, a homotopy induces a cochain map from the complex to itself, which happens to descend to the zero map in cohomology. So, if the identity cochain map from a complex to itself is a induced by a homotopy, then it descends to cohomology as both the identity map and the zero map. That is only possible when the cohomology vanishes, meaning that the complex is exact.

**Low brow explanation:**
Consider a complex of linear operators $D_i$ (meaning of course that $D_{i+1} D_i = 0$). A *homotopy* $h_i$ is a sequence of linear maps as illustrated in
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
  \cdots V_{-1} @>{D_0}>{\stackrel{\dashleftarrow}{h_0}}>
  V_0 @>{D_1}>{\stackrel{\dashleftarrow}{h_1}}>
  V_{1} \cdots ,
\end{CD}
$$
Defining the operators $N_i = h_{i+1} D_{i+1} + D_i h_i$, it is easy to check that $D_i N_i = N_{i+1} D_{i+1}$, meaning that $N_i$ constitute a *cochain map*, which is induced by the homotopy $h_i$. If $N_i = I_i$ is equal to the identity map for each $i$, then we call $h_i$ a *contracting homotopy*.

If you try to solve the equation $D_{i} v = u$, where $D_{i+1} u = 0$. Then a contracting homotopy can be used as follows:
$$
  u = I_{i} u = (h_{i+1} D_{i+1} + D_i h_i) u = D_i (h_i u) .
$$
Hence, a solution $v = h_i u$ always exists. This shows that the complex is exact, whenever a contracting homotopy exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but please I don't understand how you get the three idenity and what you mean by $[    ]$?

Comment: @Student, these are all block matrices. Multiply everything explicitly to check the identities explicitly. As an exercise, to check your understanding, reproduce the same identities by using $R_A(\mu)$.

Comment: Ok thank you. I think there is a small mistake. You use $\Lambda$ but you mean $\lambda$

Comment: @Student, ah yes, a couple of typos. Thanks for noticing. Now fixed!

Comment: Dear Professor, While the three identities are obviously true, I do not know enough about the Koszul complex to see the connection. I also don't know about the connection between the eigenvalues of I and A and the Koszul complex. I hope that you explain me a bit or to propose me a good reference. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let $\mathbf{T}=(T_1,\cdots,T_d)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^d$ be a $d$-tuple of commuting operators. It is true that
$$\sigma_T(\mathbf{T})\subset \sigma(T_1)\times \cdots \times\sigma(T_d)\;?$$ If the answer a true I find another idea. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Student I have added some explanation about the use of a contracting homotopy to show that a complex is exact. This is actually a more general version of the same argument as the one given in the last paragraph of your quote from Taylor (there, $b$ is the homotopy map). As to the spectral inclusion question, I suspect yes, but I have worked out only the case for $d=2$ (basically, my answer above).